# Middlemanapp: unknown extension

Tags: middleman

I run from console:

```
middleman build
```

and i get

```
== Unknown Extension: smusher
== Unknown Extension: favicon_maker
```

my Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem "middleman", "~>3.0.0"
gem "middleman-smusher"
gem "middleman-favicon-maker"
```

i run bundle install and bundle update.
What could the problem be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the root of your project should be a `config.rb` file. Within that file you should add two extensions to the build configuratio:

```
configure :build do
 activate :smusher
 activate :favicon_maker
end
```

[Middleman configuration Guide](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/configuration/#toc_3)